# How to set random seed when it is in distributed training in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, parallel-processing, distributed

Now I am training a model using `torch.distributed`, but I am not sure how to set the random seeds. For example, this is my current code:

```py
def main():
    np.random.seed(args.seed)
    torch.manual_seed(args.seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed(args.seed)

    cudnn.enabled = True
    cudnn.benchmark = True
    cudnn.deterministic = True 

    mp.spawn(main_worker, nprocs=args.ngpus, args=(args,))
```

And should I move the

```py
    np.random.seed(args.seed)
    torch.manual_seed(args.seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed(args.seed)

    cudnn.enabled = True
    cudnn.benchmark = True
    cudnn.deterministic = True
```

into the function `main_worker()` to make sure every process has the correct seed and cudnn settings? By the way, I have tried this, and **this behavior will make the training 2 times slower**, which really confused me.

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: use `torch.cuda.manual_seed_all()` instead of `torch.cuda.manual_seed`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! But could I use torch.cuda.manual_seed() in every process?(every process will use a single GPU)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spawned child processes do not inherit the seed you set manually in the parent process, therefore you need to set the seed in the `main_worker` function.

The same logic applies to `cudnn.benchmark` and `cudnn.deterministic`, so if you want to use these, you have to set them in `main_worker` as well. If you want to verify that, you can just print their values in each process.

`cudnn.benchmark = True` tries to find the optimal algorithm for your model, by benchmarking various implementations of certain operations (e.g. [available convolution algorithms](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/0d9e3b48c4ef54a7b5395c501ee370a8eba34bad/aten/src/ATen/native/cudnn/Conv.cpp#L442-L450)). This will take time to find the best algorithm, but once that is done, further iterations will potentially be faster. The algorithm that was determined to be the best, only applies to the specific input size that was used. If in the next iteration you have a different input size, the benchmark needs to be run again, in order to determine the best algorithm for that specific input size, which might be a different one than for the first input size.

I'm assuming that your input sizes vary, which would explain the slow down, as the benchmark wasn't used when it was set in the parent process. `cudnn.benchmark = True` should only be used if your input sizes are fixed.

`cudnn.determinstic = True` may also have a negative impact on the performance, because certain underlying operations, that are non-deterministic, need to be replaced with a deterministic version, which tend to be slower, otherwise the deterministic version would be used in the first place, but that performance impact shouldn't be too dramatic.